# Can't start the portable version of NetBeans 6.9.1 IDE

Tags: netbeans, netbeans-6.9, portable-executable, portable-applications

I downloaded the portable version of netbeans netbeans-6.9.1-201007282301-ml.zip from the netbeans site and changed the config file in etc/netbeans.conf as indicated on the netbeans site.  The file contents are below.

```
# ${HOME} will be replaced by JVM user.home system property
#netbeans_default_userdir="${HOME}/.netbeans/6.9"
netbeans_default_userdir=".netbeans/6.9"

# Options used by NetBeans launcher by default, can be overridden by explicit
# command line switches:
netbeans_default_options="-J-client -J-Xss2m -J-Xms32m -J-XX:PermSize=32m -J-XX:MaxPermSize=200m -J-Dapple.laf.useScreenMenuBar=true -J-Dapple.awt.graphics.UseQuartz=true -J-Dsun.java2d.noddraw=true"
# Note that a default -Xmx is selected for you automatically.
# You can find this value in var/log/messages.log file in your userdir.
# The automatically selected value can be overridden by specifying -J-Xmx here
# or on the command line.

# If you specify the heap size (-Xmx) explicitely, you may also want to enable
# Concurrent Mark & Sweep garbage collector. In such case add the following
# options to the netbeans_default_options:
# -J-XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -J-XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled -J-XX:+CMSPermGenSweepingEnabled
# (see http://wiki.netbeans.org/wiki/view/FaqGCPauses)

# Default location of JDK, can be overridden by using --jdkhome <dir>:
#netbeans_jdkhome="/path/to/jdk"
netbeans_jdkhome="C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_24\"

# Additional module clusters, using ${path.separator} (';' on Windows or ':' on Unix):
#netbeans_extraclusters="/absolute/path/to/cluster1:/absolute/path/to/cluster2"

# If you have some problems with detect of proxy settings, you may want to enable
# detect the proxy settings provided by JDK5 or higher.
# In such case add -J-Djava.net.useSystemProxies=true to the netbeans_default_options.
```

But it refuses to start when i try to run it.  If i change the JDK path to something incorrect it complains that it can't find the jdk so i think the jdk path is correct.  It also creates a .netbeans directory when i try to start it.  I don't see any errors and it just doesn't do anything else observable.

Does anybody know how to set up this version of netbeans?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually got it to work with netbeans 7.  I don't remember the exact steps but basically I had to modify the config file as expected but the key was to run it from command line which game some exception messages which directed me onto the right path.  Thanks for everyone's help.

Answer (score 1):

Your netbeans_default_userdir relative path will point to your installation folder, in which it is not allowed. Try to change it to another directory.

After that, try to execute again the netbeans.exe. I would suggest you to run it from command prompt. There will be more explanation on startup error.

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

Did you try using `/` instead of `\`? That should resolve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

I found with NB 7.0.1 RC1 the .conf file settings are ignored as given in the default .conf file (found in Netbeans installation). If you execute an NB application from the command line you get a message about the userdir and Netbeans directories matching because the default_userdir parameter is not being read properly.

Removing "netbeans_" from the parameter names in the new custom .conf file fixed the problem for me. I don't know if that applies to 6.9.1 or not, or just an anomaly in my environment.

i.e.

default_userdir="${HOME}/.${APPNAME}/dev"